# Find and use XML Configuration file with spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration-files

So I have a requirement for a spring filter where there are some urls that do not need to be redirected, because we just introduced responsive design.

I want to have an xml config like this:

```
<config>
   <pages>
       <url>/some/responsive/url/1</url>
       <url>/some/responsive/url/2</url>
       ...
   </pages>
</config>
```

And my filter to look like this:

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(!isResponsiveUrl(request.getServletPath())) {
            response.sendRedirect(externalUrl); //redirecto to a 3th party which provide us responsiveness
            return;
        } 
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

I have a resources folder where I want to put my xml, can someone help me find a way of reading this xml and getting the url list to implement the `isResponsiveUrl`?

Can spring find this config file automatically, and how?

I don't mind if the file isn't XML, it could be a .properties file!

The goal with this, is that if we need to add more pages, we can just update the file without restarting the app.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a util:list and use @Resource to inject on your attribute:

XML will look like this:

```
<util:list id="pages">
   <value>/some/responsive/url/1</value>
   <value>/some/responsive/url/2</value>
</util:list>
```

On Java, simply annotate the attribute:

```
@Resource(name="pages")
private List<String> pages;
```

OBS: Don't forget to include spring-util.xsd to your bean definitions.

You can take more information on [Spring doc site](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html).

I hope I´ve helped